# Visual Studio 2008 'CrystalDecisions' could not be found

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2008, crystal-reports

I'm quiet new to Crystal report but expert with SSRS.

I'm trying to load the C# Web Project which uses the crystal reports. When I try to build I am getting the error message below:

> The referenced component 'CrystalDecisions.CrystalReports.Engine'
>   could not be found.

Could anyone please help me from where to install CrystalDecisions.  I had a look at http://support.microsoft.com/kb/317789 which explains Crystal Report is already included in VS2008.

Not sure what I'm doing wrong here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

More than likely the CrystalReports Runtime is not installed on your machine.  You may be able to download from [here](http://scn.sap.com/docs/DOC-7824)

Comment: Broken Link... please fix that

Comment: Thanks for letting me know that the link was broken, just updated it

Answer (score 0):

For anyone finding this in 2018 and using a newer version of Visual Studio, you need to download the latest Crystal runtimes.

If you just want to download: http://www.crystalreports.com/crystal-reports-visual-studio/

If you want more detailed information: https://wiki.scn.sap.com/wiki/display/BOBJ/Crystal+Reports%2C+Developer+for+Visual+Studio+Downloads

The runtime currently support:

- VS 2010 – original release and higher
- VS 2012 – SP 7 and higher
- VS 2013 – SP 9 and higher
- VS 2015RC – SP14
- VS 2015 – SP 15 and higher
- VS 2017 - SP 21 and higher